# Create desktop shortcut to Windows Store app on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I found my Windows Store app I would like to launch from the desktop under C:/Program Files/WindowsApps in a subdirectory.

However when I seect it Windows says, "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." Creating a shortcut did not help. The shortcut displays the same error dialog.

I right-clicked the application and selected the security tab. "Users" does not have read & execute permissions, but there is no edit button in the properties dialog.

Comment: Did you try putting it on the Task Bar?

Comment: Yes it is in the task bar and start menu. I tried to follow the instructions at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you-try-to-install-update-or-start-a-program-or-file-46361133-47ed-6967-c13e-e75d3cc29657 which show an edit buttn in the file properties dialog however no such button shows up on my Windows system.

Comment: I am looking at Store (Windows 10 and 11) and i am pretty sure you cannot put it on the Desktop. Just Start Menu and Task Bar.